# Ошибка при конвертации .py в .exe

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

Пытаюсь сконвертировать программу,написанную на python3.6 в .exe-файл. Для этого установил cx_Freeze, idna. Создал файл setup.py, в который поместил код:

**setup.py**

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None    

executables = [Executable("2048.py", base=base)]

packages = ["idna","os","random","time"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {    
        'packages':packages,
    },    
}

setup(
    name = "2048",
    options = options,
    version = "1.0",
    description = 'A standart 2048 game',
    executables = executables
)
```

В той же директории, где находится файл setup.py, лежит 2048.py, который нужно перевести в .exe.

Ввожу команду

> python setup.py build

После чего вылезает ошибка:

> ImportError: Invalid syntax in 2048.py

Фрагмент кода из 2048.py:

```
import idna
import os
import random
import time
```

[image]
Как это можно исправить?
Код программы 2048.py:

```
#в программе используется длина строки через a[0], так как предполагается, что
#все строки в массиве равны по длине
#при использовании других видов массива, например,
#[x,x,x,x,x]
#[x,x,x]
#[x,x,x,x]
#[x,x,x,x]
#[x,x]
#необходимо полностью переработать функции moved, added, canMove, canAdd
#
#также в функция canMove имеет место быть, потому что при первом её вызове
#игровое поле уже не пустое
import idna
import os
import random
import time


LEFT = 'l'
RIGHT = 'r'
UP = 'u'
DOWN = 'd'

score = 0
addToScore = [0]

gameField = [
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0]
]

#создание копии массива
def copyOfArray(array):
    newArray = []
    for t in range(len(array)):
        newArray.append([])
        for k in range(len(array[t])):
            newArray[t].append(array[t][k])

    return newArray

#в одной случайной пустой(== 0) ячейке создаётся число(2 или 4)
def spawnPellet(array):
    forSpawn = [2,2,2,2,2,2,4]
    arrayOfZeros = []
    choice = []
    for t in range(len(array)):
        for k in range(len(array[t])):
            if array[t][k] == 0:
                arrayOfZeros.append([t,k])

    choice = random.choice(arrayOfZeros)
    array[choice[0]][choice[1]] = random.choice(forSpawn)

#преобразование столбца в строку
def columnToRow(array,columnNumber):
    column = []
    for t in range(len(array)):
        column.append(array[t][columnNumber])

    return column

#проверка строки (или столбца в виде строки) на завершённость хода в направлении 
#direction (Left или Right)
def finallyMoved(row,direction):
    if direction == RIGHT:
        for t in range(len(row)-1):
            if row[t] != 0 and row[t+1] == 0:
                return False
    if direction == LEFT:
        for t in range(len(row)-2,-1,-1):
            if row[t] == 0 and row[t+1] != 0:
                return False

    return True

#движение вниз или вправо
def moveDownOrRight(columnOrRow):
    #0100 -> 0100 -> 0010 -> 0001
    while(finallyMoved(columnOrRow,RIGHT)) != True:
        for t in range(len(columnOrRow)-1):
            if columnOrRow[t+1] == 0 and columnOrRow[t] != 0:
                columnOrRow[t],columnOrRow[t+1] = 0,columnOrRow[t]

    return columnOrRow

#движение вверх или влево
def moveUpOrLeft(columnOrRow):
    #0100 -> 0100 -> 0100 -> 1000
    while(finallyMoved(columnOrRow,LEFT)) != True:
        for t in range(len(columnOrRow)-2,-1,-1):
            if columnOrRow[t] == 0 and columnOrRow[t+1] != 0:
                columnOrRow[t],columnOrRow[t+1] = columnOrRow[t+1], 0

    return columnOrRow

#движение в определённую сторону (direction)
def moved(array,direction): 
    if direction == DOWN:
        for t in range(len(array)):
            newColumn = moveDownOrRight(columnToRow(array,t))
            for k in range(len(newColumn)):
                array[k][t] = newColumn[k]

    if direction == UP:
        for t in range(len(array)):
            newColumn = moveUpOrLeft(columnToRow(array,t))
            for k in range(len(newColumn)):
                array[k][t] = newColumn[k]

    if direction == LEFT:
        for t in range(len(array[0])):
            moveUpOrLeft(array[t])

    if direction == RIGHT:
        for t in range(len(array[0])):
            moveDownOrRight(array[t])

#можно ли подвинуть строку/столбец
def canMove(array):
    for t in range(len(array)):
        for k in range(len(array)):
            if array[t][k] == 0:
                return True
    return False

#проверка: было ли какое-то изменение в массиве после движения
def wasChanged(array, direction):
    wasMoved = wasAdded = True
    newArray1 = copyOfArray(array)
    newArray2 = copyOfArray(array)

    moved(newArray1,direction)
    if newArray1 == array:
        wasMoved = False
    if wasMoved == True:
        return True

    added(newArray2,direction)
    if newArray2 == array:
        wasAdded = False

    if wasAdded == True:
        return True

    return False

#проверка на возможность сложения
def canAdd(array):
    #проверка на возможность сложения элементов в строке
    for t in range(len(array)):
        for k in range(len(array[t])-1):
            if array[t][k] == array[t][k+1]:
                return True
    #проверка на возможность сложения элементов в столбце
    for t in range(len(array)-1):
        for k in range(len(array[t])):
            if array[t][k] == array[t+1][k]:
                return True

    return False

#сложение чисел в направлении direction
def added(array,direction):
    global addToScore
    addToScore = [0]
    if direction == LEFT:
        for t in range(len(array)):
            for k in range(len(array[0])-1):
                if array[t][k] == array[t][k+1] and array[t][k] != 0:
                    array[t][k] += array[t][k+1]
                    array[t][k+1] = 0
                    addToScore.append(array[t][k])

        return array

    if direction == RIGHT:
        for t in range(len(array)):
            for k in range(len(array[0])-2,-1,-1):
                if array[t][k] == array[t][k+1] and array[t][k] != 0:
                    array[t][k+1] += array[t][k]
                    array[t][k] = 0
                    addToScore.append(array[t][k+1])

        return array

    if direction == UP:
        for t in range(len(array)-1):
            for k in range(len(array[0])):
                if array[t][k] == array[t+1][k] and array[t][k] != 0:
                    array[t][k] += array[t+1][k]
                    array[t+1][k] = 0
                    addToScore.append(array[t][k])

        return array 

    if direction == DOWN:
        for t in range(len(array)-2,-1,-1):
            for k in range(len(array[0])):
                if array[t][k] == array[t+1][k] and array[t][k] != 0:
                    array[t][k] += array[t+1][k]
                    array[t+1][k] = 0
                    addToScore.append(array[t][k])

        return array

#отрисовка игрового поля
def drawGame(array):
    os.system('clear')
    print("  '2048' ")
    for t in array:
        print(t)
    print('score = ', score)

#приветствие
def welcome():
    hello = ["__  __           _          _           ","|  \/  | __ _  __| | ___    | |__  _   _ ",
    "| |\/| |/ _` |/ _` |/ _ \   | '_ \| | | |","| |  | | (_| | (_| |  __/   | |_) | |_| |",
    "|_|  |_|\__,_|\__,_|\___|   |_.__/ \__, |","                                   |___/",
    " _____                _                              ","|__  /___ _ __ ___   / \   _ __ _ __ ___   ___  _ __ ",
    "  / // _ \ '__/ _ \ / _ \ | '__| '_ ` _ \ / _ \| '__|"," / /|  __/ | | (_) / ___ \| |  | | | | | | (_) | |   ",
    "/____\___|_|  \___/_/   \_\_|  |_| |_| |_|\___/|_|  "]

    anim = "|/-\\"
    idx = 0
    while idx < 50:
        time.sleep(0.06)
        print(40*anim[idx%len(anim)] + "\r",end=' ')
        idx +=1
    idx = 0
    for t in hello:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print(t)
    while idx < 30:
        time.sleep(0.06)
        print(anim[idx%len(anim)] + "\r",end=' ')
        idx +=1
    print('\n')

#цикл, в котором всё крутится
def main():
    global score, addToScore
    while True:
        drawGame(gameField)
        if canMove(gameField) == False and canAdd(gameField) == False:
            drawGame(gameField)
            print('You Lose')
            break
        else:
            direction = input('Введите движение: ')
            if wasChanged(gameField,direction) == True:
                moved(gameField, direction)
                added(gameField, direction)
                moved(gameField, direction)

                for t in range(len(addToScore)):
                    score += addToScore[t]

                spawnPellet(gameField)
            else:
                continue

welcome()
spawnPellet(gameField)
spawnPellet(gameField)
main()
```

Comment: Приведенного фрагмента 2048.py недостаточно: в нем явно нет синтаксических ошибок.

Comment: [_2048.py_](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/JLkt/MWpQGB3pn)

Comment: Добавьте в сам вопрос, там не так уж много кода.

Comment: Кстати, насколько я понимаю, скрипт у вас для Python3, а cx_freeze вы используете от Python2

Comment: В таком случае, как это можно проверить или использовать cx_freeze для python3?